# can adaptive cards in bot framework v3 contain dynamic dropdowns

Tags: c#, botframework, dropdown, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I'm using BOT Framework v 3 i have an adaptive card that takes input from the user and i want the values in Dropdown to be dynamic  is it possible.here is the adaptive card design code as you can see I have entered the choices manually instead it want it to be dynamic from the database

```
var card = new AdaptiveCard()
{
    Body = new List<CardElement>()
    {
        new TextBlock()
        {
            Color = TextColor.Attention,
            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
            Size = TextSize.Medium,
            Text = "Select a title",
        },
        new ChoiceSet()
        {
            Id = "title",
            Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Compact,
            IsRequired = false,
            IsMultiSelect = false,
            Value = "1",
            Choices = new List<Choice>()
            {
                new Choice()
                {
                    Title = "Swiss cargo",
                    Value = "Swiss cargo",
                },
                new Choice()
                {
                    Title = "ticket booking",
                    Value = "ticket booking",
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you are expected to show your attempt first and show where you are encountering a problem, please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you using the `Microsoft.AdaptiveCards` NuGet package? You should really be using the one just called `AdaptiveCards` instead.

Comment: This looks like it's more of a question about using data from your database than a question about Adaptive Cards. Can you show us how you're retrieving the data?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: yes@KyleDelaney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get your data into a list of strings, your Adaptive Card can easily be constructed dynamically using Linq. If you want to keep using the same Adaptive Cards library, it would look like this:

```
var data = new List<string> { "Swiss cargo", "ticket booking" };

var card = new AdaptiveCard()
{
    Body = new List<CardElement>()
    {
        new TextBlock()
        {
            Color = TextColor.Attention,
            Weight = TextWeight.Bolder,
            Size = TextSize.Medium,
            Text = "Select a title",
        },
        new ChoiceSet()
        {
            Id = "title",
            Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Compact,
            IsRequired = false,
            IsMultiSelect = false,
            Value = "1",
            Choices = data.Select(item => new Choice { Title = item, Value = item }).ToList(),
        },
    },
};
```